# Associate Software Engineer -- what does "associate" mean?

Tags: software-industry, job-description, title

I received an offer for a "Senior Associate Software Engineer" role. What does 'associate' mean here?

Some web pages (such as [this question on programmers.se.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112694)) suggest that it means 'junior' or 'entry level'. Does it mean that I will be a senior among the juniors? :)

<sub>FWIW, I don't really care about the title, as long as the opportunity is interesting. I'm just curious.</sub>

Comment: My guess.  It is meaningless.  Or only has meaning, in that particular company.

Comment: It might refer to the type of software engineering that you'd be doing. Perhaps the primary engineers work on the software that the company sells, and associate engineers work on internal software.

Comment: @DavidYaw: that's true! How did you get it?

Comment: I think I have yo agree that this is too company-specific for us to answer. Ask HR what the job titles are at that employer, what their expectations are for a Senior Associate,  what the next band/title is and how many years it typically takes to earn that promotion. The answers _may_ be on the company's job-openings website these days.

Comment: @keshlam: of course I'm going to ask my company. I was just wondering whether the 'associate' term had a common meaning or not. The duties of a  "Software Engineer" depend on the company too, but that term has a common meaning (more or less)

Comment: No, job titles are not well standardized across companies,  and may not be well standardized across roles within a single company.

Comment: As Joe said,  means what they want it to.   I know of a US Bank with a dev centre where I live,  you are an associate until you become a Vice President,  and then a Director,  so totally no analogue to the real world.

Comment: Are you permanently employed by the organisation, or on a contract/freelance basis?

Comment: @MarvMills: permanently

Comment: I means their are going to pay less salary for you...............

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An associate is lower ranked. Typically used instead of trainee in my experience. An 'Associate Software Engineer' looks better than 'Trainee Software Engineer'.

It basically means that you're lower ranked than the person who does not have it in their title.

Comment: Yep, it does sound a bit silly, but I would think the definition for 'associate' still holds as lower ranked than without it. I worked for a company where most everyone was a 'Senior Engineer' and 'Associate Senior Engineer' were the trainee's from the local tech college. There was no title of just 'Engineer' at all.

Comment: I've seen "associate" attached to entry-level employees but also to team leaders who have just recently been promoted to be such. It appears to be mostly about sounding more prestigious than  "junior". I guess it feels OK if you are labelled junior in the beginning of your career but less so when you have already worked hard for years to earn a position. Your employer might wish to highlight you are now to that particular career level.

Seems like an oxymoron when used in combination with "senior", though.

Comment: That depends on country but the UK 'associate'  is used for roles not requiring a Degree eg these with BTEC / HNC / ONC

Answer (score 3):

An associate is typically someone who does not have a significant time on the job or in the profession.  In technical fields this title is usually 3-7 years to progress from junior though senior associate and into a base level engineer.  Though that is not a hard and fast rule just how long it takes most people, I have seen, to be promoted.

A senior associate is someone who may be relatively new to the company and or field, but that has shown the ability to successfully complete their assigned work.  Typically they would have stronger skills than an entry level associate but still have not shown the abilities that would merit a promotion to full software engineer.  This does not mean that you do not have the skills just that they have not been demonstrated, but that you have been recognized as being at a higher level than a base associate.  It also indicates a high level of expectations.  A senior associate should not need much guidance in the completion of most tasks.

Comment: Associate is used in the legal field also in nearly the same context.  Typically limited to describe a position or employee who isnt vested or "matured" in the company.

Comment: Really depends on country  in the UK a new grad may well be called an engineer from the start  getting your CENG takes a lot longer